# TFS Build - C# 7.0 System.ValueType

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops

I try to setup a continuous integration build on VisualStudio.com to build my project. Since I upgraded to .net 4.6.2 and working with the System.ValueType, the build fails:

> MinimalMonitoringClient\MMCThinNetwork\Connection.cs(91,23): Error
>   CS1519:  Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member
>   declaration Connection.cs(91,23): error CS1519: Invalid token '(' in
>   class, struct, or  interface member declaration 
>   [d:\a\1\s\MinimalMonitoringClient\MMCThinNetwork\MMCThinNetwork.csproj]
>   MinimalMonitoringClient\MMCThinNetwork\Connection.cs(91,47): Error
>   CS1044:  Cannot use more than one type in a for, using, fixed, or
>   declaration statement Connection.cs(91,47): error CS1044: Cannot use
>   more than one type in a for,  using, fixed, or declaration statement 
>   [d:\a\1\s\MinimalMonitoringClient\MMCThinNetwork\MMCThinNetwork.csproj]
>   MinimalMonitoringClient\MMCThinNetwork\Connection.cs(91,64): Error
>   CS1002: ;  expected

- It compiles on my local computer
- The NuGet Package "System.ValueType" is installed
- No Package Folder on TFS
- The Task "Restore NuGet Packages" is included in the build process
- NuGet Restore Build Step finishes successfully

> 2017-04-22T14:42:13.2402898Z ##[section]Starting: NuGet restore
>   **/*.sln 2017-04-22T14:42:13.2512895Z ============================================================================== 2017-04-22T14:42:13.2512895Z Task         : NuGet Installer
>   2017-04-22T14:42:13.2512895Z Description  : Installs or restores
>   missing NuGet packages 2017-04-22T14:42:13.2512895Z Version      :
>   0.2.31 2017-04-22T14:42:13.2512895Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation 2017-04-22T14:42:13.2512895Z Help         : [More
>   Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613747)
>   2017-04-22T14:42:13.2512895Z
>   ============================================================================== 2017-04-22T14:42:14.3517087Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com
>   65001 2017-04-22T14:42:14.3517087Z Active code page: 65001
>   2017-04-22T14:42:14.4246880Z Detected NuGet version 3.3.0.212 / 3.3.0
>   2017-04-22T14:42:14.4276880Z SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
>   2017-04-22T14:42:14.4286876Z To connect to NuGet feeds hosted in your
>   Team Services account/TFS project collection on this build agent, edit
>   your build definition to choose a higher version of nuget or specify a
>   path to a NuGet.config containing the package sources you wish to use.
>   2017-04-22T14:42:14.4316868Z
>   [command]d:\a_tasks\NuGetInstaller_333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b\0.2.31\node_modules\nuget-task-common\NuGet\3.3.0\NuGet.exe
>   restore -NonInteractive
>   d:\a\1\s\MinimalMonitoringClient\MinimalMonitoringClient.sln
>   2017-04-22T14:42:15.2210188Z MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild
>   version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
>   2017-04-22T14:42:15.4566895Z Feeds used: 2017-04-22T14:42:15.4566895Z 
>   C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache
>   2017-04-22T14:42:15.4576898Z   https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
>   2017-04-22T14:42:15.4576898Z  2017-04-22T14:42:15.4786896Z Restoring
>   NuGet package System.ValueTuple.4.3.0. 2017-04-22T14:42:15.4896877Z
>   Restoring NuGet package Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.2.
>   2017-04-22T14:42:16.5110192Z Adding package 'System.ValueTuple.4.3.0'
>   to folder 'd:\a\1\s\MinimalMonitoringClient\packages'
>   2017-04-22T14:42:16.5330192Z Added package 'System.ValueTuple.4.3.0'
>   to folder 'd:\a\1\s\MinimalMonitoringClient\packages'
>   2017-04-22T14:42:16.7550436Z Adding package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.2'
>   to folder 'd:\a\1\s\MinimalMonitoringClient\packages'
>   2017-04-22T14:42:16.7780484Z Added package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.2' to
>   folder 'd:\a\1\s\MinimalMonitoringClient\packages'
>   2017-04-22T14:42:16.8080211Z ##[section]Finishing: NuGet restore
>   **/*.sln

- In Build Solution the VS Version is set to: 2017
- Clean: True
- Restore NuGet Packages: True

Thanks in advance

Comment: msbuild version 14, it's not using Visual Studio 2017 compiler, it's using 2015 version.

Comment: Even with 2015 settings, I doesn't compile successfully. Same exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the Hosted VS2017 Build Agent to compile things using VS2017.

[image]